# Applying colors via mousedown can only be overwritten if I choose a color with an index value greater than the current color index

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, d3.js

My simple mapping software allows for different colors to be applied to counties. I've been struggling with a rather odd bug that only allows colors with an index value greater than the current color index to overwrite the color.

The code is long, but I'm not sure if the point can be made without pasting the entire thing. I will start with the main pieces:

Here is the `getColor()` function that populates the array of hex colors and where I believe part of the problem lies:

```
function getColor(index) {
        var colorarray = [
            '550000',
            '801515',
            'aa3939',
            'd46a6a',
            'ffaaaa',
            '003333',
            '0d4d4d',
            '226666',
            '407f7f',
            '669999',
            '004400',
            '116611',
            '2d882d',
            '55aa55',
            '88cc88',
            '552700',
            '804515',
            'aa6c39',
            'd49a6a',
            'ffd1aa',
        ];
        return colorarray[index];
    }
```

Here is the code in it's entirety. The bug is noticed quickly if you choose the last color in the array (bottom right, pinkish color), select some counties, and then try and overwrite. You'll see that it fails. If you choose the top right, dark red color, you can overwrite that color with any other color because all are farther down the array list.

It uses the colorsjs.js and d3.js libraries.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Heartland Remapping Tool</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/faviconpng.png" />
<style>
    svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    input {
        border-width: 0px;
        border: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 3px;
    }

    .c550000 {
        fill: #550000;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c801515 {
        fill: #801515;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .caa3939 {
        fill: #aa3939;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .cd46a6a {
        fill: #d46a6a;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .cffaaaa {
        fill: #ffaaaa;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c003333 {
        fill: #003333;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c0d4d4d {
        fill: #0d4d4d;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c226666 {
        fill: #226666;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c407f7f {
        fill: #407f7f;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c669999 {
        fill: #669999;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c004400 {
        fill: #004400;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c116611 {
        fill: #116611;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c2d882d {
        fill: #2d882d;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c55aa55 {
        fill: #55aa55;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c88cc88 {
        fill: #88cc88;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c552700 {
        fill: #552700;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .c804515 {
        fill: #804515;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .caa6c39 {
        fill: #aa6c39;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .cd49a6a {
        fill: #d49a6a;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .cffd1aa {
        fill: #ffd1aa;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .counties {
        fill: white;
        stroke: #7887AB;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .counties .hovered,
    .counties :hover {
        fill: #061539;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .selected {
        fill: #061539;
    }

    .erase {
        fill: none;
    }

    .deselected {
        fill: white;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .deselected :hover {
        fill: #061539;
        stroke-width: .5px;
    }

    .county-borders {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #F0F8FF;
        stroke-width: .2px;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .state-borders {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #162955;
        opacity: .8;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .toolTip {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        min-width: 80px;
        height: auto;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #6F257F;
        padding: 14px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var selcolor;
    window.onload = function() {
        var defaultcolor = document.getElementById("first");
        getSeletedColor(defaultcolor);
    };

    //this may be the cause of the fact that I can only overwrite colors with a color farther down the list.
    function getColor(index) {
        var colorarray = [
            '550000',
            '801515',
            'aa3939',
            'd46a6a',
            'ffaaaa',
            '003333',
            '0d4d4d',
            '226666',
            '407f7f',
            '669999',
            '004400',
            '116611',
            '2d882d',
            '55aa55',
            '88cc88',
            '552700',
            '804515',
            'aa6c39',
            'd49a6a',
            'ffd1aa',
        ];
        return colorarray[index];
    }

    function getSeletedColor(val) {

        var coloritem = document.getElementById('selcolor');
        coloritem.value = val.value;
        var dispitem = document.getElementById('current_color');
        dispitem.style.background = val.style.backgroundColor;
        dispitem.value = val.value;
    }
</script>
<input id="selcolor" hidden="true" value="hhhhhh"></input>
<div id="option">
    <input style="width: 90px; height: 18px;" name="updateButton" type="button" value="Print Regions" onclick="dl_csv()" />
</div>
<div id="option">
    <input style="width: 90px; height: 18px;" name="updateButton" type="button" value="Reset" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
</div>
<br/>
<div>
    <form id="colorlist">
        <input id="first" style="background-color:#550000; color: #550000;" value="550000" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#801515; color: #801515;" value="801515" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#aa3939; color: #aa3939;" value="aa3939" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#d46a6a; color: #d46a6a;" value="d46a6a" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#ffaaaa; color: #ffaaaa;" value="ffaaaa" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <br/>
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#003333; color: #003333;" value="003333" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#0d4d4d; color: #0d4d4d;" value="0d4d4d" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#226666; color: #226666;" value="226666" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#407f7f; color: #407f7f;" value="407f7f" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#669999; color: #669999;" value="669999" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <br/>
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#004400; color: #004400;" value="004400" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#116611; color: #116611;" value="116611" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#2d882d; color: #2d882d;" value="2d882d" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#55aa55; color: #55aa55;" value="55aa55" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#88cc88; color: #88cc88;" value="88cc88" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <br/>
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#552700; color: #552700;" value="552700" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#804515; color: #804515;" value="804515" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#aa6c39; color: #aa6c39;" value="aa6c39" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#d49a6a; color: #d49a6a;" value="d49a6a" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
        <input spellcheck="false" style="background-color:#ffd1aa; color: #ffd1aa;" value="ffd1aa" onmousedown="getSeletedColor(this)">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <input readonly hidden="true" style="background:white; width: 50px;" id="current_color" value="550000"></input>
    <form action="">
        <input style="margin: default; height: 18px; width: 15px;" type="radio" name="tool" value="zoompan" id="zoompan"> <u>Z</u>oom/Pan
        <input style="margin: default; height: 18px; width: 15px;" type="radio" name="tool" value="select" id="select" checked> <u>S</u>elect
        <input style="margin: default; height: 18px; width: 15px;" type="radio" name="tool" value="erase" id="erase"> <u>E</u>rase
    </form>
    <form action="">
        <input style="margin: default; height: 18px; width: 15px;" type="radio" name="map" value="county" checked> County
        <input style="margin: default; height: 18px; width: 15px;" type="radio" name="map" value="state"> State
        <input style="margin: default; height: 18px; width: 15px;" type="radio" name="map" value="other"> Other
    </form>
</div>

<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jscolor.js"></script>-->
<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg");
    var path = d3.geoPath();
    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

    var clickDown = true;
    var color_selcounties = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        color_selcounties[getColor(i)] = [];
    }
    var selectedCounties = [];
    var uniqueCounties = [];
    var selectedCountiesNum = selectedCounties.length;
    var t = [
        ['color', 'fips']
    ];
    var csvRows = [];

    var expArray = [
        ['color', 'fips']
    ];

    var region = function() {
        //Dedupes the list of counties, this ensures no counties are double bucketed.
        uniqueCounties = selectedCounties.filter(function(elem, pos) {
            return selectedCounties.indexOf(elem) == pos;
        });
        console.log("Master: " + uniqueCounties);

        //Dedupes the list of counties by region.
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (color_selcounties[getColor(i)].length >= 1) {
                var uniqueColorCounties = color_selcounties[getColor(i)].filter(function(elem, pos) {
                    return color_selcounties[getColor(i)].indexOf(elem) == pos;
                });
                console.log(getColor(i) + ": " + uniqueColorCounties);
                t.push([getColor(i), uniqueColorCounties]);
            }
        }
    }

    var tools = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("zoompan").checked) {
            alert("zoompan");
        } else if (document.getElementById("select").checked) {
            alert("select");
        } else if (document.getElementById("erase").checked) {
            document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        } else {

        }
    }

    function dl_csv() {
        region();
        var csvString = expArray.join("%0A");
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + csvString;
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.download = 'myFile.csv';

        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    }

    d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json", function(error, us) {
        if (error) throw error;

        let hoverEnabled = false;
        var mousedown = function() {
            if (document.getElementById("select").checked) {
                var self = d3.select(this);
                hoverEnabled = !self.classed('hovered');

                if (hoverEnabled) {

                    selectedCounties.push(this.__data__.id);
                    var color = document.getElementById('selcolor').value;
                    self.classed("c" + color, true);

                    color_selcounties[color].push(this.__data__.id);
                    expArray.push([color, this.__data__.id]);

                } else {
                    var ix = selectedCounties.indexOf(this.__data__.id);
                    selectedCounties.splice(ix, 1);
                }

            } else if (document.getElementById("erase").checked) {
                var self = d3.select(this);

                self.classed('deselected', true);

                var ix = selectedCounties.indexOf(this.__data__.id);
                selectedCounties.splice(ix, 1);
            }
        }

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "counties")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.nation).features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", path);
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.nation, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "state-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "county-borders")
            .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) {
                return a !== b;
            })));


        svg.selectAll('.counties path')
            .on('mousedown', mousedown)
            .on('mouseup', function() {
                hoverEnabled = false;
            })
            .on('mouseover', function() {

                tooltip
                    .style("left", 500 + "px")
                    .style("top", 70 + "px")
                    .style("display", "inline-block")
                    .html(this.__data__.id);

                var color = document.getElementById('selcolor').value;
                var self = d3.select(this);

                if (hoverEnabled) {

                    self.classed("deselected", false);
                    self.classed("c" + color, true);

                    selectedCounties.push(this.__data__.id);
                    color_selcounties[color].push(this.__data__.id);
                    expArray.push([color, this.__data__.id]);
                }
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(d) {
                tooltip.style("display", "none");
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have two options: either you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which doesn't seem to be an option in your case, or you provide the whole code, **as long as it is a working code**. Right now that's a huge code, which we cannot even test (since we don't have the topoJSON). So, put all this in a Plunker or something like that, and it will be easier for everyone.

Comment: Hello Gerardo, the full code is in the original post. It's the code snippet below the sentence talking about the libraries it uses.

Comment: I know, and that's exactly what I meant: it's the full code, but not a **working** code.

Comment: I edited the jscolor.js source. The code should now work without you having to download the library.

Comment: Like wow. This is not the way I'd write this solution. There seems to be a massive reliance on `color_selcounties[ 'aabbcc' ]` where `aabbcc` comes from a) calling getColor() 20 times, b) #selcolor. Why not rewrite #selcolor to be #selcounty and use `getColor(county)`. It'd probably clear up a lot of your issues (and code in general)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this...

```
self.classed("c" + color, true);
```

You are simply **adding** classes (in the "hexadecimal order"), but not removing the existing ones.

Because of that, your elements will have several classes...

```
class = "foo bar baz"
```

... and the prevalent color will be the color set by the **last class** in the style sheet, which explains the behaviour you're seeing now.

**Solution**: A simple solution is just changing it to:

```
self.attr("class", "c" + color);
```

Which overwrites any previously existing class. Do the same for the other `classed` functions.

Here is your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/zbvxk4xv/

Comment: PS: Have in mind that I'm answering your question, and your question only. Right now, your code has problems, which means that it has a lot of room for improvements: you could simplify it a lot.

Comment: Also, the `erase` function applies a `deselected` class which prevents new colours from being applied. This can be changed to `self.attr("class", '');`

Comment: Good catch, @Gnippots, just changed that too.